# How can I get the maximum date from two union tables in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I Currently have the following SQL, 2 union tables in a CTE. Currently the MAX(DSTAMP) is returning the max from the 2 union tables (2 records) and what I want is the max date when both are combined (1 single record).

SQL is in Oracle Server.

```
With TA as

(select
    SKU_ID, CODE, FROM_LOC_ID, TO_LOC_ID, EXTRA_NOTES, CONTAINER_ID,
    PALLET_ID, DSTAMP, USER_ID, UPDATE_QTY, ORIGINAL_QTY, LOCK_CODE
from  table 1
WHERE CODE = '####'
AND SITE_ID = '9999'
AND FROM_LOC_ID NOT IN ('####')


UNION

select
    SKU_ID, CODE, FROM_LOC_ID, TO_LOC_ID, EXTRA_NOTES, CONTAINER_ID, 
    PALLET_ID, DSTAMP, USER_ID, UPDATE_QTY, ORIGINAL_QTY, LOCK_CODE
from  table 2
WHERE CODE = '####'
AND SITE_ID = '9999'
AND FROM_LOC_ID NOT IN ('####')

)


SELECT
    SKU_ID, CODE, FROM_LOC_ID, TO_LOC_ID, EXTRA_NOTES, CONTAINER_ID, 
    PALLET_ID, USER_ID, UPDATE_QTY, ORIGINAL_QTY, LOCK_CODE,
    MAX(DSTAMP) as DSTAMP

FROM TA
GROUP BY
   SKU_ID, CODE, FROM_LOC_ID, TO_LOC_ID, EXTRA_NOTES, CONTAINER_ID,
   PALLET_ID, USER_ID, UPDATE_QTY, ORIGINAL_QTY, LOCK_CODE
```

Comment: If you're getting two rows when you expect one then there must be a difference in the values you're grouping by. Without seeing sample data and your current and expected result for that data, we can't tell where the problem lies - in your data, or in your expectations, or somewhere else.

Comment: You are getting two rows because of the values of  group by columns. The union has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

For a single record with the max, I would add an having clause with the condition for example :

```
HAVING MAX(DSTAMP) = (SELECT MAX(DSTAMP) FROM TA)
```